# Passing the custom field values in the wp_get_current_user array function

Tags: php, functions, custom-field

**How to pass the custom field values which were stored while creating a new user into the `wp_get_current_user` array function**

When I call the `wp_get_current_user()` function the result which I found is as follows:

```
WP_User Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 20
            [user_login] => testing
            [user_pass] => $P$BAfSwYFZEUKIkQyF30Eq7GN3HOUXFW/
            [user_nicename] => testing
            [user_email] => testing@testing.com
            [user_url] => 
            [user_registered] => 2015-12-15 07:11:35
            [user_activation_key] => 1450163495:$P$Br7QHNREuY.esEZdB3c92fK2CrW9QH.
            [user_status] => 0
            [display_name] => testing testing
            [token_key] => 
        )

    [ID] => 20
    [caps] => Array
        (
            [subscriber] => 1
        )

    [cap_key] => wp_capabilities
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [0] => subscriber
        )

    [allcaps] => Array
        (
            [read] => 1
            [level_0] => 1
            [subscriber] => 1
        )

    [filter] => 
)
```

But I want the answer to be as

```
WP_User Object
    (
        [data] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID] => 20
                [user_login] => testing
                [user_pass] => $P$BAfSwYFZEUKIkQyF30Eq7GN3HOUXFW/
                [user_nicename] => testing
                [user_email] => testing@testing.com
                [user_url] => 
                [user_registered] => 2015-12-15 07:11:35
                [user_activation_key] => 1450163495:$P$Br7QHNREuY.esEZdB3c92fK2CrW9QH.
                [user_status] => 0
                [display_name] => testing testing
                [token_key] => 
                [client] => abc
                [user_groups] => test
            )

        [ID] => 20
        [caps] => Array
            (
                [subscriber] => 1
            )

        [cap_key] => wp_capabilities
        [roles] => Array
            (
                [0] => subscriber
            )

        [allcaps] => Array
            (
                [read] => 1
                [level_0] => 1
                [subscriber] => 1
            )

        [filter] => 
    )
```

Compare the **[data]** part of both the array

How do I achieve this?

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this like.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user->data->client = $user->client; // $user->meta_key
$user->data->user_groups = $user->user_groups; // $user->meta_key
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question. No need to pass the values in the array we can call the separate function to get the values of the custom fields based on the current user for e.g. `get_user_meta($current->ID);`